# Swift, I am having problem to associate and store array of travel modes to a tripchain

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mvvm

first of all this is my first question on stackoverflow. I need help, I am stucked since 3 weeks on this :').
WHAT I HAVE TILL NOW:
I am creating an app that, though out firebase api, stores data of interviewed about thei trip habits. I have created a view inside thr app that allows to a user to create her/his trip chain.
So in example, in my average day I depart from home to work and I do this movement in 20 minutes and with two modes (car and then metro). Then after work I go to gym, again this time I use bus and take 15 mins. From gym I go to restaurant with motorbike, in 10 minutes, and at the end of the day I return at home with metro and car. (crearly my trip chain is different from the one of another person). So based on the code that I will paste, I would like to store the information about the transport mode used (I woul like to have the possibility to chose different travel mode to compose my trip chain if needed and time required). I have already created an enum of modes, than 2 pickers to choose the departing place and the destination, and  I am able to store such information on firebase trough viewModel architecture..I am facing difficulties in associating an array of modes and time to each single movement of the trip chain. In the following code, After the second LabelledDivider("Your trip"). the user should have the possibility to visualize the actual trip chain that she/he is composing. Thank you so much in advice... there is also a screen how the ui is till now

```
//
//  tripChain.swift
//  SPSURVEY
//
//  Created by Christian Riccio on 30/01/23.
//

import SwiftUI


struct DiaryView: View {
    @Binding var viewModel: InterviewedViewModel
    @State var trips: [Trip] = []
    @State var selectedTrip: Trip? = nil
    @State var showAdd = false
    @State var showAddTrip = false
    @State var locations = ["Casa", "Lavoro", "Palestra", "Ristorante", "istruzione", "svago"]
    //    @State var modes = ["car", "bus", "train", "scooter", "motorbike", "bycicle", "metro", "tram", "piedi"]
    @State var selectedModes: [Modes] = []
    @State var viaggio = []
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                
                HStack {
                    if(viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.count > 0){
                        Button{
                            
                            viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.append(Trip(departing: viewModel.interviewed.TripChain[viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.count - 1].arrival , arrival: "", mode: selectedModes, time: "20"))
                            showAdd = true
                            
                            
                        } label: {Image(systemName: "plus")}
                    }
                }
                .onAppear(){
                    viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.append(Trip(departing: "Casa", arrival: "Casa", mode: selectedModes, time: "20"))
                    showAdd = true
                    viaggio = viewModel.interviewed.TripChain
                }
                .padding()
                LabelledDivider(label: "Compose your trip")
                if(showAdd){
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        HStack(spacing: 7){
                            Text("Destination 1: ")
                            Picker("", selection: $viewModel.interviewed.TripChain[ viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.count - 1].departing) {
                                Text(viewModel.interviewed.TripChain[ viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.count - 1].departing).tag(viewModel.interviewed.TripChain[ viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.count - 1].departing)
                                ForEach(locations, id: \.self) {value in
                                    Text(value).tag(value)
                                }
                            }.labelsHidden()
                                .pickerStyle(.menu)
                        }
                        HStack(spacing: 7){
                            Text("Destination 2: ")
                            Picker("", selection: $viewModel.interviewed.TripChain[ viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.count - 1].arrival) {
                                Text(viewModel.interviewed.TripChain[ viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.count - 1].arrival).tag(viewModel.interviewed.TripChain[ viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.count - 1].arrival)
                                ForEach(locations, id: \.self) {value in
                                    Text(value).tag(value)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        ForEach(0..<viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.count) { index in
                            
                            
                            HStack{
                                Text("Transport mode:")
                                //                                HStack {
                                ForEach(selectedModes, id: \.self) { mode in
                                    Text(mode.stringName())
                                }
                                //                                }
                                //                                .padding(.trailing, 60)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    selectedModes = []
                                    showAddTrip = true
                                    selectedTrip = viewModel.interviewed.TripChain[index]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //                            Text("Transport Mode: ")
                        //                            Picker("", selection: $viewModel.interviewed.TripChain[ viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.count - 1].mode) {
                        //                                ForEach(Modes.allCases, id: \.self) { mode in
                        //                                    Text(mode.stringName()).tag(mode)
                        //                                }
                        //                            }
                        //
                        //                            .pickerStyle(.menu)
                        //                            .padding(.trailing, 60)
                        //                        }
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            
                            viaggio = viewModel.interviewed.TripChain
                            viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.append(Trip(departing: viewModel.interviewed.TripChain[viewModel.interviewed.TripChain.count - 1].arrival , arrival: "???", mode: selectedModes, time: "20"))
                            
                        }, label: {Text("conferma")})
                    }
                }
                
                
                
                
                LabelledDivider(label: "Your Trip")
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal){
                    HStack(spacing:5){
                        if(viaggio.count > 0){
                            Text(viewModel.interviewed.TripChain[0].departing)
                            
                            
                            ForEach(viewModel.interviewed.TripChain,id: \.self) { trip in
                                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5){
                                    
                                    //                                Text(trip.departing)
                                    
                                    VStack(spacing:5){
                                        Image(systemName: "arrow.right").font(.title3)
                                        HStack(spacing:3){
                                            Text(trip.time)
                                            //                                            Image(trip.mode[0].imageName())
                                        }
                                        
                                    }
                                    Text(trip.arrival)
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

MY PROBLEM:

I'd like to have a new picker (or something else) that gives me the possibility to chose one or more different travel modes. Such travel modes belongs to an enum of Modes that I have already created.  I am not able to select multiple travel modes and associate them to each one of the movement of the trip chain that I am composing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRI0R.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might want to consider a couple things: 1) Format your post so it isn't one long paragraph 2) Make clear what the _specific_ problem is. You describe a general problem, but not the specific issue you're hitting 3) Include a [mre] -- your post depends on a lot of code not included here, so even if there _were_ a specific problem described, it'd be impossible for the answerer to write/test code to fix it.

Comment: I am so sorry, I am new on SO, so thanks for these suggestions.

Comment: Refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.